# MySQL order by DATETIME on a simple join takes 30 seconds

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization, sql-order-by

I have a very simple mysql query join for storing records of instagram profiles and their posts.

profiles table = 2500 records (PK = p.id)

post_files table = 800,000 records (PK = pf.id)

```
SELECT 
    p.id,  
    p.instagram_id,
    pf.filename,
    p.last_updated_on,
    count(pf.id) as total_images


FROM 
    profiles p JOIN post_files pf ON p.instagram_id = pf.instagram_id
    
    
WHERE
     pf.filetype = 'photo'
    
group by 
    p.id
    
order by 
  p.last_updated_on ASC
    
LIMIT 0,200;
```

I even have **single column indexes** added on columns:

- pf.filetype
- p.last_updated_on

Using the EXPLAIN syntax on the query yields the following result:

[image]

The query is so basic with a single table inner join but takes about 30 seconds to run. The database has the potential to grow to 10 million records but even at 800K records, it is unusable. Makes me think I am missing something very fundamental in a basic table join with sort.

What can I do to make this run faster?

Comment: The explain is suggesting possible key fields, have you tried this? also group by without aggregate function is probably not useful, perhaps order by p.id,p.last_updated_on,  and there is no where clause?

Comment: I am not versed with MySQL's `EXPLAIN` output. To me it *looks* like `profiles.instagram_id` is considered a primary key in that output, but in that case your query would probably be invalid and the mere existence of an additional `profiles.id` questionable. Could you please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements, so we see the primary and foreign keys used? It is confusing to see an `instagram_id`, but no `instagram` table. Does such a table exist? Then please include it in the request. Tell us what the tables represent and how they are related.

Comment: The fields of join should be indexed. In this SQL execution plan, where, tem and filesort are the reasons for slow query.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry I had removed the COUNT() query to make the query simpler. added it back again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner profiles.id and post_files.id are the PKs. instagram_id is just the column which contains the numerical instagram id of the profile.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question. Also, you're misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY. Please [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: As previously requested, please add the full `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables ([`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)). Is `instagram_id` unique or can the same one be assigned to multiple profiles? Your current query should be raising an error due to `pf.filename` not being functionally dependant on your `GROUP BY` clause. If not, you have [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled, which is generally a bad thing, unless you fully understand the implications.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is invalid. So before talking about performance, you should get the query fixed. You group by `profiles.id`, but you select `post_files.filename`. Which? There may be thousands of file names linked to a profile. The DBMS should raise an error here, but you say you can run it. That means that you run in MySQL's notorious cheat mode that allows invalid aggregation queries. In early MySQL versions this cheat mode was even the default, which either means you are running an old MySQL version or you changed the default to cheat mode. You shouldn't do either. In MySQL, always work in full group by mode:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Then you are joining on an ID that is not unique in either of the two tables, if I understand you correctly. This means your join can end up with 0 to 2,500 x 800,000 = 2,000,000,000 result rows. (0 with no ID matching, 2 billions with all IDs maching, i.e. all IDs being the same. Or any number between.) The only condition for limiting this result is the filetype, which you want to be "photo", but well, as this is about Instagram, this may not be very limiting. In the worst case, the DBMS tries to sort 2 billions of joined rows.

Let us see, what the DBMS is supposed to do. I am illustrating the approach I might take, the DBMS may choose another approach to get to the same result.

1. Zero photos found yet.
2. Get the latest updated profile
3. Show their Instagram photos, until you either read them all or hit a total of 200 photos already.
4. If not 200 photos found yet, get next latest profile and continue with step 3.

The first question is: Is this really what you want? Show all Instagram photos of the latest updated profile and then maybe some more? This looks like a weird task to me.

If you want this, then we can help the DBMS to find the latest updated profiles quickly and get their Instagram IDs for the join:

```
create index idx1 on profiles (last_updated_on, instagram_id);
```

And then we want to find the Instragram's photo files quickly. We come with an Instagram ID and want to know the file type:

```
create index idx2 on post_files (instagram_id, filetype);
```

If that doesn't help, then this may be one of the rare cases where using a loop in your app and running separate queries (one per lately updated profile) may be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

Your exceptionally poor performance

> *"about 30 seconds to run"*

does make me wonder whether you have some configuration issues. It would be helpful to know what MySQL version you are running, and on what OS? Does your dataset fit in the buffer pool?

You may get a significant performance improvement by moving the pagination to a subquery (or CTE if you prefer). This query is still very much dependant on adding the two indices suggested by Thorsten.

```sql
SELECT p.*, ANY_VALUE(pf.filename), COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT p.*
    FROM profiles p
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM post_files
        WHERE filetype = 'photo' AND instagram_id = p.instagram_id
    )
    ORDER BY p.last_updated_on ASC
    LIMIT 0,200
) p
JOIN post_files pf ON p.instagram_id = pf.instagram_id AND pf.filetype = 'photo'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.last_updated_on ASC;
```

Note the use of [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) as `pf.filename` is not functionally dependant on your `GROUP BY` clause.

I mocked up a dataset with 2.5K and 800K rows (probably very different distribution to yours) and was not able to reproduce your poor performance. Even with only your single column indices, your original query returned in about 1.5 seconds.

I have created these six indices, initially set to invisible:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON profiles (instagram_id) INVISIBLE;
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON profiles (last_updated_on) INVISIBLE;
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON profiles (last_updated_on, instagram_id) INVISIBLE;

CREATE INDEX idx1 ON post_files (instagram_id) INVISIBLE;
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON post_files (filetype) INVISIBLE;
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON post_files (instagram_id, filetype) INVISIBLE;
```

Your original query with only PKs (0.469s):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p |  | ALL | PRIMARY |  |  |  | 2500 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pf |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 798639 | 0.01 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |

Your original query with only the idx1 indices (1.413s):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p |  | index | PRIMARY,idx1 | PRIMARY | 4 |  | 2500 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pf |  | ref | idx1 | idx1 | 4 | test.p.instagram_id | 310 | 50.00 | Using where |

Your original query with idx1 & idx2 indices (1.328s):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pf |  | ref | idx1,idx2 | idx2 | 1 | const | 398212 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p |  | ref | PRIMARY,idx1,idx2 | idx1 | 4 | test.pf.instagram_id | 1 | 100.00 |  |

Your original query with idx1, idx2 & idx3 indices (0.573s):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | p |  | index | PRIMARY,idx1,idx2,idx3 | PRIMARY | 4 |  | 2500 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pf |  | ref | idx1,idx2,idx3 | idx3 | 5 | test.p.instagram_id,const | 107 | 100.00 | Using index condition |

My suggested query with the pagination moved to the derived table (0.078s):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 200 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pf |  | ref | idx1,idx2,idx3 | idx3 | 5 | p.instagram_id,const | 107 | 100.00 | Using index condition |
| 2 | DERIVED | p |  | index | idx1 | idx3 | 9 |  | 200 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | post_files |  | ref | idx1,idx2,idx3 | idx3 | 5 | test.p.instagram_id,const | 107 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index; FirstMatch(p) |

**Rick's query is a lot faster, at least with my test dataset (0.013s)**:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p |  | index |  | idx3 | 9 |  | 200 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pf |  | ref | idx1,idx2,idx3 | idx3 | 5 | test.p.instagram_id,const | 107 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index |

P.S. These were all run on my local MySQL 8.0.33 instance. Query times included above are the averages of ten executions.

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed, the `GROUP BY` is bad, both because of the `filename` and because of performance.  Let's get rid of it:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.instagram_id, p.last_updated_on,
        ( SELECT count(*) FROM post_files AS pf
              WHERE p.instagram_id = pf.instagram_id
                AND pf.filetype = 'photo'
        ) as total_images
    FROM  profiles AS p
    ORDER BY  p.last_updated_on ASC
    LIMIT  0,200;
```

Notice how this rummages through pf only 200 times, not for all profiles.

Recommended indexes:

```
p:  INDEX(last_updated_on, instagram_id)
pf:  INDEX(instagram_id, filetype)
```

If `last_updated_on` really comes from `pf`, then flip this all inside-out.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest try removing group by from the query if ID is unique. Also, check the buffer size in Mysql configuration.

Comment: sorry I had removed the COUNT() query to make the query simpler. added it back again.

Comment: Please add the link to the references that supports your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).